# Activate a conda/mamba environment when cd to a specific directory

Tags: ubuntu, bash, bashrc

Can I automatically activate a specific environment when `cd` into a directory? Like if I `cd` into the directory `my_nn_library` then automatically run `mamba activate nn_env`. I am using Ubuntu.

Comment: What OS/Linux distro? Have you looked into what sorts of programming you can build into bashrc?

Comment: I am using ubuntu. Found the solution, posting as an answer below for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

I am appending the following lines to the `.bashrc`:

```
# Activate conda env when cd into a specific directory
function cd () {
    builtin cd "$@"
    if [[ $@ == *"MatGNN"* ]] ; then
        mamba activate matgnn
    fi
}
```

It uses the builtin `cd` and then based on condition can execute certain commands. Here if the argument to `cd` contains the string `MatGNN` then activate the environment. It works on Ubuntu and should also work on macOS.